# retrive time value in yii

Tags: php, yii

hello friends I am newbie to Yii.I have the date and time in mysql database. I just want to know how to retrieve the date and time from mysql.How to write the query in view.php file of yii framework.

Comment: please be much more specific about what you are having trouble with. connecting to the database? running a query? retrieving results? displaying results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this guide to configure [yii](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/03/configuring-yii/#more-583).

Then make sure you configured gii in the above guide and go to yourwebapp/index.php/gii/.  This assumes you’re using the URL management component in Yii. If not, head to yourwebapp/index.php?r=gii.  Click the generate model link.  Then type the name of your table into the form.  Click generate.  This will generate you an Active directory class for that table.  This process is explained with screen shots [here](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/07/creating-models-views-and-controllers-in-yii-2/).

Now lets say that generated a model from a table called transaction.  That model should be located in your models folder.  You can call this model in your controllers.  Something like:

SiteController:

```
function actionIndex()
  {
    $model = new Transaction();
    $model->find('id=:id', array(':id'=>10));
    $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model));
  }
```

In the sites folder under views you would insert this `$model` object somewhere in the index view:

```
<div><?php echo $model->theNameOfYourDateColumn ?></div>
```

Here is the diffinitive yii guide's page for [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar).